# Sortable divs that slide over each other

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to make a page with scrollable divs that slide away from each other when one of them is being clicked and dragged within a restricted box area. Another requirement is that it is angularized and that the divs only travel along the Y axis. Here is what I have so far, but for some reason the animation isn't working. Where am I going wrong?

```js
app.controller('docMasterStepController', ['$scope', '$window', 'DocMasterSteps', 'DocMasterStepsUpdate', function ($scope, $window, DocMasterSteps, DocMasterStepsUpdate) {
  var rowHeld = -1;
  var lastShift;
  var lastOff;
  var turned = false;
  var y = 0;
  var backX = 0;
  var backY = 0;
  var emptySlot = -1;
  var flip = 1;
  var hideButtons = false;
  var fresh = false;
  var turnedAgain = 1;
  var firstShift;
  var dragged = 0;
  var lastCheck;
  var upDown;
  var myPos;
  var thisPos;
  var timeout;
  var s = $scope;
  var matrix = [];

  s.initialize = function(id)
  {
    DocMasterSteps.get({id: id}, function(resp){
      s.doc = resp.doc;
      s.dc = resp.dc;
      s.steps = resp.steps;
      s.hiddenButtons = [];
      s.textbox = [];
      for (var step in s.steps)
      {
        s.hiddenButtons[step] = true;
        s.textbox[step] = s.steps[step].step_nomenclature;
      }
      s.$apply();
      for (var step in s.steps)
        s.renumber($('.draggable').get(step), false);
    });
  };

  s.destroy = function(event, bool, index)
  {
    s.steps.splice(index, 1);
    s.$apply();
    s.targetRenumber(event, bool);
  };

  s.targetRenumber = function(event, bool)
  {
    s.renumber(event.target, bool);
  };

  s.setPosition = function(myPos)
  {
    matrix[myPos] = true
  };

  s.hideButtons = function(index)
  {
    s.hiddenButtons[index] = true;
  };

  s.showButtons = function(index)
  {
    s.hiddenButtons[index] = false;
  };

  s.moveCursor = function(event)
  {
    var target = event.target;
    if (target.setSelectionRange)
    {
      target.setSelectionRange(9999, 9999)
    }
    target.value = target.value;
  };

  s.getFocus = function(down){
    var downer = down.target;
    var reminder = $(downer).attr('name');
    $('div[name="' + reminder + '"]').get(0).previousElementSibling.focus();
  };

  s.getUp = function(up) {
    var upper = up.target;
    firstShift = $(upper).parent();
    dragged = 0;
    turnedAgain = 1;
    fresh = false;
    hideButtons = true;
    rowHeld = $(upper).attr('name');
    myPos = rowHeld;
    emptySlot = rowHeld;
    $(upper).css('z-index','75');
    $($(upper).get(0).previousElementSibling).css('z-index','25');

    backX = $(upper).css('left');
    backY = $(upper).css('top');
  };

  s.getDown = function(down) {
    var downer = down.target;
    hideButtons = false;

    var reminder = ~~$(downer).attr('name');
    var lastReminder = ~~$($(lastOff).children()[1]).attr('name');

    $(downer).css('z-index','50');
    var myBox = $($(downer).get(0).previousElementSibling);
    myBox.css('z-index','0');

    $(".draggable").animate({
      top: 0
    }, { duration: 0, queue: false }, function() {
    });

    var holder = s.steps[reminder];
    s.steps.splice(reminder, 1);
    s.steps.splice(lastReminder, 0, holder);

    holder = s.textbox[reminder];
    s.textbox.splice(reminder, 1);
    s.textbox.splice(lastReminder, 0, holder);

    s.$apply();
    for (var step in s.steps)
      s.renumber($('.draggable').get(step), false);

    $('div[name="' + lastReminder + '"]').get(0).previousElementSibling.focus();
  };

  s.renumber = function(dis, clear)
  {
    if(clear) {
      $(dis).parent().css('display','none');
      $(dis).parent().parent().parent().get(0).outerHTML+=$(dis).parent().parent().parent().get(0).outerHTML;
      var j = 0;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < $('.sNames').length; i++)
    {
      if (clear)
      {
        if((parseInt($(dis).parent().attr('class').split('s')[1])+1) == i)
        {

          $($('.textbox').get(i)).attr('value','');
          $($('.fakeInput').get(i)).attr('name','i');
          $($('.textbox').get(i)).attr('id','doc_step' + (0-i) + '_step_nomenclature');
          $($('.textbox').get(i)).attr('name','doc_step[step_nomenclature][' + (0-i) + ']');
          $($('.textbox').get(i)).focus();
        }
      }

      $($('.sNames').get(i)).html('Step ' + (i + 1) + ':');
      $($('.fakeInput').get(i)).attr('name',i);
      $($('.textbox').get(i)).css('z-index',i);
      $($('.fakeinput').get(i)).css('z-index',40+i);
      $($($('.row').children().get(i)).children().get(2)).attr('class','buttons' + i);
    }

    matrix = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $('.sNames').length; i++)
    {
      matrix[i] = false;
    }


    $('.draggable').attr('class','draggable droppable');

    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
      axis: "y",
      refreshPositions: true
    });

    $(".draggable").animate({ top: 0 }, 0 );

    $(".droppable").droppable({
      tolerance: 'pointer',
      greedy:true,
      over: function(event, ui) {
        thisPos = parseInt($($(event.target).children().get(1)).attr('name'));
        //alert(thisPos);

        dragged = ui.position.top;
        if(!lastCheck)
        {
          upDown = ui.position.top > 0;
        }
        else {
          upDown = dragged > lastCheck;
        }
        lastCheck = dragged;


        //$(':animated').not($('.draggable').get(parseInt($($(lastShift).children().get(1)).attr('name')))).not(event.target).finish();
        //$('.draggable').not().finish();


        $window.clearTimeout(timeout);

        //holdMe = $('[name=\"' + thisPos + '\"]').parent().html();
        //timeout = setTimeout("$('[name=\"' + thisPos + '\"]').mouseup()", 3000);

        ;

        lastShift = $(event.target);

        if (!firstShift)
        {
          firstShift = lastShift;
        }

        if (lastShift && lastOff)
        {
          turned = lastShift.get(0) == lastOff.get(0);
        }

        fresh = true;

        flip = upDown ? 1 : -1;
        var child;

        matrix[parseInt(thisPos)] = false;
        if ((($(event.target).css('top') == '0px') || ($(event.target).css('top') == 'auto'))) {

          if (parseInt(thisPos) > parseInt(myPos)) {

            for (var i = thisPos; thisPos > parseInt(myPos); thisPos--)
            {
              $($($($('.row').get(thisPos)).children().get(0)).children().get(0)).animate({
                top: -30
              }, {duration: 300, queue: false}, function () {
              });
            }
          } else if (parseInt(thisPos) < parseInt(myPos)) {
            for (var i =thisPos; thisPos < parseInt(myPos); thisPos++)
            {
              $($($($('.row').get(thisPos)).children().get(0)).children().get(0)).animate({
                top: 30
              }, {duration: 300, queue: false}, function () {
              });
            }
          }
          else
          {
            $(event.target).animate({
              top: 0
            }, { duration: 300, queue: false }, function() {
            });
          }
        }
        else
        {
          $(event.target).animate({
            top: 0
          }, { duration: 300, queue: false }, function() {
          });
        }
      },

      out: function(event, ui) {
        var higher;

        lastOff = $(event.target);

        var len = $('.draggable').length-2;

        if (turned) // && (lastOff.get(0) != $('.draggable').get(1)) && (lastOff.get(0) != $('.draggable').get(len)))
        {

          $(event.target).animate({
            top: 0
          }, {duration: 300, queue: false}, function () {
          });
        }

      }
    });
  }}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <h3>Title: <input class="titlebox" id="doc_master_nomenclature" name="doc_master[nomenclature]" value="<%= @doc.nomenclature %>" style="padding-left:4px;width:600px" /> </h3>
    <div class="well" ng-controller="docMasterStepController" ng-init="initialize(<%= @id %>)">
      <div class="contain" />
      <div class="row" ng-repeat="step in steps" ng-hide="hiddenRows[$index]" ng-mouseover="setPosition($index)">
        <div class="col-md-12" ng-mouseleave="hideButtons($index)" ng-mouseover="showButtons($index)">
          <div class="draggable droppable" style="padding-left:42px,top:0px,left:0px;position:relative;width:650px;display:inline-block;">
            <input class="textbox form-control required" id="doc_step{{step.id}}_step_nomenclature" name="doc_step[step_nomenclature][{{step.id}}]" ng-model="textbox[$index]" type="text" ng-focus="moveCursor($event)" style="padding-left:4px;z-index:0;width:600px;height:30px;position:relative;top:-2px;left:50px;" />
            <div class="fakeInput" name="{{$index}}" ng-click="getFocus($event)" ng-mousedown="getUp($event)" ng-mouseup="getDown($event)" style="z-index:50;width:568px;height:30px;position:absolute;top:-2px;left:50px;"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="sNames" style="padding-left:6px;z-index:0;width:600px;height:30px;position:absolute;top:3px;left:0px;font-weight: 700" ng-bind="step.step_number + ': '"></div>
          <div style="display:none" ng-hide="hiddenButtons[$index]">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 10px;padding:3px 8px;" ng-click="targetRenumber($event, true)">
              <a href="#added" style="color:white; font-size: small">Add Step After</a>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" style="padding:3px 8px;" ng-click="destroy($event, false, $index)">
              <a href="#removed" style="color:white; font-size: small">Remove Step</a>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" style="padding:3px 8px;">Add Buys</button>
            <button type="button" style="padding:3px 8px;" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
              Add Data Master
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h2 style="color:#31708f; visibility: hidden; margin-right: 420px; display:inline-block;" class="saved">
        Saving...
      </h2>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="Cancel" style="margin-top:15px;" onclick="window.location.href = '../<%= @doc.id %>'" />
      <input onclick="$('.saved').css('visibility','visible')" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:15px;" id="commit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Save">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Check this library : http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-sortable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the wrong format. You are going to have to use directives:

```
app.directive('sortRows', ['$timeout', '$parse', function ($timeout, $parse) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.sortRows);
            scope.$watch(model, function (value) {
              // put sorting jquery in here
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```